# vb.net application RS485 ascii communication

Tags: vb.net, automation, serial-port, rs485, industrial

I have built a vb.net application that ran on a pc using RS232 and communicated with a serial device.  The application worked great.  The application has migrated to use an industrial PC with a RS485 port that will automatically convert my RS232 to RS485.  My question is the device I am working with has a default RS485 address of 7.  I am unsure how this address works with ascii RS485.  I know how the addressing works with modbus over 485 but not with ascii communication (the specifical type of communication is **SCPI** *Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments*).

I am using the standard .net **System.IO.Ports.SerialPort** class and not sure how this RS485 address fits in with this communication scheme.

Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to prefix the command with the address number like this

```
Public Property GateAddress As String = "A007"
SerialPort.Write(GateAddress + "Some ASCII Command" + vbCrLf)
```